# Collation in Postgresql DB level,table level, column level

Tags: postgresql, collation

I have database created with Collation type 'C' with UTF8 characterset. If I create any table or index under same database will it be having the Collation 'C' or I need to explicitly define at the time on table or index creation.

How we can extract the details of collate for table and indexes in postgresql 11

database create with collate 'C' also created table and idexes without explicitly collate type.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE testdb
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'C'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    TABLESPACE = testts
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    TEMPLATE = template0;

create table test1c (id integer, content varchar(10));
create index idx_test on test1c(content);
```

Need information about collate on table and index level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collation of a column is stored in the `attcollation` of the column's `pg_attribute` row.  A value of 100 signifies the “default collation”, which is the database collation stored in `pg_database`.

This is a way to find the collation of all columns for a table:

```
WITH defcoll AS (
   SELECT datcollate AS coll
   FROM pg_database
   WHERE datname = current_database()
)
SELECT a.attname,
       CASE WHEN c.collname = 'default'
            THEN defcoll.coll
            ELSE c.collname
       END AS collation
FROM pg_attribute AS a
   CROSS JOIN defcoll
   LEFT JOIN pg_collation AS c ON a.attcollation = c.oid
WHERE a.attrelid = 'test1c'::regclass
  AND a.attnum > 0
ORDER BY attnum;

 attname | collation 
---------+-----------
 id      | 
 content | C
(2 rows)
```

For indexes, the collations are stored in the column `pg_index.indcollation`:

```
WITH defcoll AS (
   SELECT datcollate AS coll
   FROM pg_database
   WHERE datname = current_database()
)
SELECT icol.pos,
       CASE WHEN c.collname = 'default'
            THEN defcoll.coll
            ELSE c.collname
       END AS collation
FROM pg_index AS i
   CROSS JOIN unnest(i.indcollation) WITH ORDINALITY AS icol(coll, pos)
   CROSS JOIN defcoll
   LEFT JOIN pg_collation AS c ON c.oid = icol.coll
WHERE i.indexrelid = 'idx_test'::regclass
ORDER BY icol.pos;

 pos | collation 
-----+-----------
   1 | C
(1 row)
```

Comment: So Does it means, That If I create my database with specific Collate Type, the the objects (Tables,Indexes, columns) will be having the same Collate type right?

Comment: Yes, unless you explicitly specify a different collation.